# Where did HazelCast map.get() go? And scalability concerns

Tags: scalability, hazelcast

According to [this](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.5/manual/html/map-nearcache.html), "Each map.get(k) will be a remote operation" But where is the remote? For example, I have a node that writes into the IMap with key - k. Another 50 nodes that does read from the IMap using map.get(k). What happens when 50 nodes call map.get(k). Does each call come to the node that does the write? If so, how many copies of IMap does this "remote" node will create in responds to these 50 calls? Is it multi-threaded? Is this IMap singleton? Or each thread will create a deep copy of such IMap?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But where is the remote?

The answer is in the preceding sentence in the documentation link you supplied: "Imagine that you are reading the key k so many times and k is owned by another member in your cluster.". Each key is hashed and mapped to a partition, as explained in http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.7/manual/html-single/index.html#sharding-in-hazelcast and the "Data Partitioning" section that follows. The cluster member that owns that partition is the owner (or primary replica) of the key. Each read & write on that key will be executed by the same thread on that particular member (that is unless your configuration allows read from backup).

> What happens when 50 nodes call map.get(k). Does each call come to the node that does the write?

Yes, it's always the key owner the one that executes operations on that key.

> If so, how many copies of IMap does this "remote" node will create in responds to these 50 calls?

The member only has one instance of the IMap, no copies.

> Is it multi-threaded?

No, all map operations involving the same key `k` will be executed on the same partition thread on the same member which is the primary replica of that key. You may read more about threading model of operations in http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.7/manual/html-single/index.html#operation-threading

Comment: If I enable nearcache, I will get stale data? So that's not desirable. I should always go to the remote key owner. I don't see a use case for nearcache.

Comment: @johnsam with `invalidate-on-change` config, near cache will subscribe for change events. If data was changed in the remote member, client will read it from remote and store in near cache.

Comment: greate. Is nearcache an implementation of JCache?

Comment: Actually near cache is invisible to you. You just use Map API and the first time you do a map.get or a put the local near cache will be populated with this key's value. Next time you do a get for that same key, near cache will provide it without the need to issue a remote call to the owner member. Hazelcast also implements JCache API (see http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.7/manual/html-single/index.html#jcache-overview) , but it is a separate API you can use instead of Map. Near cache is also available for JCache API when you use the java hazelcast client to access data on a cluster.